# second player in a two player game can't enter if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am new to firebase and "persistent" data. I am trying to make a rock paper scissors game and can get two players to login and show each other's login names on the other players screens. I can also have the first player pick their choice, which then increases the game.turn variable to 2 in Firebase and on the second players local data (because it will log it out in the console). However, My code will not allow entrance to the second if statement where game.turn == 2 to turn on the button listener for the second player (I know this because it doesn't print out the console.log within that section).

I have researched and tried several different things from nested ifs to else ifs to sending the data to Firebase too many times and creating infinite loops. If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it! My code for this section is below (I tried to leave out things that I didn't think were needed. I do call the functions to start them, but I didn't include that.):

```
choice: function() {
    var playersRef = game.dataInfo.child(game.players);
    var player1Ref = playersRef.child(game.player1);
    var player2Ref = playersRef.child(game.player2);

    // add turn to firebase
    game.turn++;
    game.dataInfo.update({
        turn: game.turn
    }); //  end firebase update             

    // if it is turn 1 then player 1 picks
    if (game.turn == 1) {

        // on click for player 1 choice
        $("#choices1").on('click', '.piece', function() {

            // updates the pick for player 1 in firebase
            player1Ref.update({pick: $(this).data('name')});
            $('#choices1').children().not(this).hide();
            game.turn++;

            // update turn to firebase
            game.dataInfo.update({
                turn: game.turn
            }); //  end firebase update

        }); // end of on click for player 1 choice

    } // end of if player 1 hasn't picked

    // if it is turn 2 then player 2 picks
    if (game.turn == 2) {
        console.log("I made it!");

        // on click for player 2 choice
        $('#choices2').on('click', '.piece', function() {

            // updates the pick for player 2 in firebase
            player2Ref.update({pick: $(this).data('name')});
            $('#choices2').children().not(this).hide();
            game.turn++;

            // update turn to firebase
            game.dataInfo.update({
                turn: game.turn
            }); //  end firebase update

        }); // end of click for player 2 choice 

    } // end if it is turn 2 then player 2 picks

}, // end of choice function

// updates local variables within game object from firebase
updateVar: function () {

    game.dataInfo.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        game.turn = snapshot.val().turn;
        console.log(game.turn);
        game.pick = snapshot.val().players[1].pick;
        console.log(game.pick);
        game.pick2 = snapshot.val().players[2].pick;
        console.log(game.pick2);
        game.wins = snapshot.val().players[1].wins;
        console.log(game.wins);
        game.losses = snapshot.val().players[1].losses;
        console.log(game.losses);
        game.ties = snapshot.val().players[1].ties;
        console.log(game.ties);
        game.wins2 = snapshot.val().players[2].wins;
        console.log(game.wins2);
        game.losses2 = snapshot.val().players[2].losses;
        console.log(game.losses2);
        game.ties2 = snapshot.val().players[2].ties;
        console.log(game.ties2);
    });

}, // end updateVar function
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spork:</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="nameForm">
                <form>
                    <div class="form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name-input"><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form">
                        <input id="connect" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="player1">
            <p id="wait1">Waiting for player 1</p>
            <div id="choices1"></div>
            <p id="score1"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4" id="winner">

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4" id="player2">
            <p id="wait2">Waiting for player 2</p>
            <div id="choices2"></div>
            <p id="score2"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="disconnect1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="disconnect2">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before the first `if` statement, you are increasing the `game.turn`:

```
// add turn to firebase
game.turn++;
game.dataInfo.update({
    turn: game.turn
}); //  end firebase update
```

If `game.turn` is 2 when entering the function, wouldn't it increase to 3 and therefore never enter the second `if` statement?

I suggest you remove the above mentioned `game.turn++;` line.

Comment: Thanks for the response! :) I'm sorry I didn't include that part of it. I start game.turn at 0 so that player 1 can't pick their choice until player 2 has joined. When player two joins it starts the choice function which makes the turns move up to one allowing entrance to the first if statement. Within that if statement it is supposed to increase to 2 so that it can enter the following if statement. According to console.logs it does increase to 2 on player 2's console and it updates to Firebase to turn 2, but it doesn't enter the if (game.turn ==2) statement.

Comment: I tried to take out what you suggested just in case and started game.turn at 1 and I ran into the same problem. If I start the turn at 0, it won't enter the first player if statement.

Comment: Well, it totally looks like when exiting the first block, it should immediately jump into second block (on the same client), since `game.turn` increases. Is it supposed to happen on the same client? Shouldn't turn 1 be played on client A and turn 2 on client B? If so, I suggest a return statement after the first `if`.

Comment: Thanks, Puppetmupp! I will look into return statements. That sounds like where I'm having the issue. :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm having trouble with what I would return to make it switch to client B. I looked up returns and I tried to add a "return game.turn;", but when I do that it doesn't move up to turn 2 anymore. I also tried to remove the game.turn++ in the player 1 choice and "return game.turn++;", but I had the same result. 

I feel like you are on to something because I think that is the issue that client B isn't moving into the second if statement, but could I bother you to give me an example of what you mean? Sorry for my n00bness and thanks for all the help you have given me so far! :D

Comment: No, sorry, I forgot this is inside an event handler, so only the code inside it will run asynchronously whenever the user clicks the choice div and not until then. This is when the choice function should be invoked on the other client/player. When is choice being invoked for player 2?

Comment: The buttons for player 2 are created before the choice function is called. Then player 2 should be able to click them in the second if statement (if (game.turn == 2)), but it isn't able to enter that if statement. It goes through the first one and then nothing happens after that.

Comment: Another suggestion is to just register the event handlers for `#choices` on game start - better to make sure to add them only once. Inside the handler, you can update the player's values to firebase. When you have received a firebase update, call a function to evaluate if it's the current player's turn, and update accordingly. If unclear, I can update with an example tomorrow.

Comment: Player 2 should never enter `if (game.turn == 1)`, right? Only Player 1 should be able to do this. Therefore, when Player 1 has finished, the `choice` function must be invoked for Player 2. Easiest way now is to invoke `choice` everytime the firebase onvalue event is triggered. This probably means you also have to implement the suggestion in my original answer and then initialize `game.turn` to 1 somewhere else, or check for 0.

Comment: I will try both of those suggestions tonight and if I can't get it, let you know for the example. Thanks again for all your help! :)

Comment: You, Puppetmupp, are a god among men/women. I salute you and thank you for your help! *salute* Calling the function for player two in the Firebase update area worked!